# Lisp - writing a function that evaluates graph node labels

Tags: graph, lisp, common-lisp, labeling

Consider a graph such as this one, composed of nodes and neighbors:

```
(defparameter *graph* '((A (B C D))
                        (B (A C E))
                        (C (A B D E))
                        (D (A C E))
                        (E (B C D))))
```

...and a set of labels for each node:

```
(defparameter *values* '((A 1)
                         (B 2)
                         (C 3)
                         (D 2)
                         (E 1)))
```

I'm trying to write a function that evaluates a graph in that format and determines whether or not adjacent nodes have the same label.  If I were writing this in C++ or Java my logic for an iterative version of the function might look something like this:

```
(defun evaluate-label (graph values)
;; for every node in graph
  ;; for every adjoining node
    ;; if (node.value == adjoiningNode.value)
      ;; return false
;; return true
)
```

...but I'm not sure what sort of logic would be more appropriate for Lisp, let alone how to go about coding it up.

So, two questions:

1. What would a "Lispy" bit of pseudocode for this function look like?
2. What specific syntactical features would you put in the function?  Let's assume there's a `cond`.  Is `every` useful for this problem?  Can we easily do this without resorting to lambda expressions?

Thanks in advance for any feedback!

Comment: With the `DOLIST` macro you can iterate over lists. Something like `RETURN` or `RETURN-FROM` might also be useful. Good luck!

Comment: @Rainer Joswig - Using `DO` or one of its variants is definitely an option.  I just can't help but think there has to be a more "Lispy" way of writing this function, with (for example) a higher-order function doing the iterating over the graph's nodes.  That's what I'm looking for here - not a solution, per se, but an approach that suits the language.

Comment: @jda Look into using 'some'.

Comment: Thanks!  I had no idea about `some`, but that's a great approach to solving the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One important aspect of good programming, regardless of the language, is good abstraction.  At times, that can be a matter of taste, but here's an example that tries to apply some abstraction to this problem.  Once you have your graph and your values, you can define a node-value function that returns the value of a node. Then you can phrase your question as

> Is there some node the graph that has the same node value as one of its neighbors?

This isn't too hard to write with **some**:

```
(defun adjacent-values-p (graph values)
  (flet ((node-value (node)
           (cadr (assoc node values))))
    (some #'(lambda (node-descriptor)
              (destructuring-bind (node neighbors)
                  node-descriptor
                (find (node-value node) neighbors
                      :key #'node-value)))
          graph)))
```

```
(adjacent-values-p '((a (b c)))
                   '((a 1) (b 2) (c 1)))
;=> C

(adjacent-values-p '((a (b c)))
                   '((a 1) (b 2) (c 3)))
;=> NIL
```

That said, even though that might be more Lisp-y in some senses, it might make just as much sense to write it using explicit iteration with **dolist**:

```
(defun adjacent-values-p (graph values)
  (flet ((node-value (node)
           (cadr (assoc node values))))
    (dolist (node-descriptor graph)
      (destructuring-bind (node neighbors) node-descriptor
        (when (member (node-value node) neighbors :key #'node-value)
          (return t))))))
```

This can be even better with **loop**, which supports some destructuring:

```
(defun adjacent-values-p (graph values)
  (flet ((node-value (node)
           (cadr (assoc node values))))
    (loop for (node neighbors) in graph
       thereis (find (node-value node) neighbors :key #'node-value))))
```

All of these versions could benefit from storing values in, e.g,. a hashtable for quicker retrieval.  Whether this makes sense to do here or not depends on your needs, application domain, etc.  Otherwise you'll be retrieving edge labels O(2×|E|), doing a O(|V|) traversal each time. For instance:

```
(let ((table (make-hash-table)))
  (flet ((node-value (node)
           (multiple-value-bind (value presentp)
               (gethash node table)
             (if presentp value
                 (setf (gethash node table)
                       (cadr (assoc node values)))))))
    ;; ...
    ))
```

That caches "on-demand" by not looking up a node value until it's needed.  However, since every node value should be needed (assuming that that the list of values provided doesn't contain any extra nodes), it's probably better to just populate the table at the beginning.  Then you don't have to do any checks later on, and you only have to traverse the values list once.  Thus:

```
(defun adjacent-values-p (graph values &aux (table (make-hash-table)))
  (loop for (node value) in values
     doing (setf (gethash node table) value))
  (flet ((node-value (node)
           (gethash node table)))
    ;; ...
    ))
```

Comment: Great answer, thank you.  Your explanations were clear and instructive, and I appreciated you walking through the rationale behind each suggestion.